# Decode SNMP OctetString with Python

Tags: python, decode, snmp

I have troubles in decoding OctetString in SNMP data
I already have data and there is not need to collect it, I just need to decode it
`{"1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.1.16.1.2.0": "Hph"}` and there shall be an integer. I am stuck (((

Comment: What have you tried? What output are you expecting?

Comment: I tried encode, decode with different params ... the output shall be number. Some integer

Comment: I found that pysnmp is sort of capable to do that, however I am stuck in trying to use it with just dict with snmp OIDs and values. It seems it requires full cycle starting with device connection

Comment: `OctetString` is in fact a byte array. So about how to decode the bytes, refer to the actual MIB document. The OID you are referring to is `usage-printer-total-charge` of `real` type, but it's not clear where the definition of `real` is. Without that you cannot interpret the data. Contact HP technical support and they might have the answer.

Comment: I have HP support answer that this is an integer. Still I cannot get how this can be turned to integer

Comment: No, they cannot merely tell you that "this is an integer", but they should guide you through the process of how to interpret the bytes. Keep in mind their MIB document says the type is `real`, so the actual calculation algorithm must be defined somewhere, and that's what you should chase them for.

Comment: So far, what they did was just telling that according to MIB this is integer and I might find useful some python tools for interpretation. I am puzzled ((

Comment: That doesn't sound right. A support engineer on this topic should be very familiar on their own MIB documents and the various data types, so that they should be able to walk you through the interpretation of raw bytes. Try to ask for escalation to a more senior support engineer who can offer you the guidance.